# How to use less Bipolar Stepper-Motor Drivers

Tags: driver, cnc

I make a CNC machine with lot of drivers (12) and the quality ones are quite expensives.

As I never use all the motors at the same time, and the fact that the unused/resting motors can be off is not a problem,

I wonder if a good strategy exist for being able to "switch" between groups of drivers (in 24V 4A), for this case I 
only need to use 4 at the same time maximum.

*In other words, is it possible to control by example 12 bipolar stepper motors with 4 drivers ?*

This would be really useful for saving money and also saving micro-controllers pins.

Comment: When a motor is not connected to a driver, it will be able to spin freely on its own, is that a desired feature of your machine?

Comment: Yep, not a problem for this one.

Comment: For unipolar steppers a combination of diods and switching the common (FETs, relais) would work. For bipolars you'd need one relais per stepper.

Comment: One relais per stepper would do it. I see no other way.

Comment: Okay, There is not like 4A shift register or something ? (I am a noob)

Comment: You'd need 4 x 4A transmission gate per stepper. I don't think those exist (for a reasonmable price).

Comment: Okay I will look, it look bloated, but thank you sir.